# Do enlightened forces use weapons and militancy as a means of self-defense?

Tags: history

I am working on a paper regarding the use of militancy (using armed tactics) by legitimate political forces to protect themselves from their opponents who are also heavily armed.

> Let's say a country is being ruled by a totalitarian regime, whether
> it be a dictator, a monarch, or even a so-called democracy, but with
> no rights or justice for the people. An enlightened group in the
> country decides to get rid of this regime initially through political
> means, but when they realize that they will face extreme reactions
> from the regime and will likely be attacked and killed in order to
> suppress their voices, they also decide to arm themselves as a matter
> of self-defense and to exist and complete their ultimate mission.

However, the initial idea of using arms by any non-state group cannot be justified, but can it be justified in a situation such as the one mentioned, where the groups who seek progressive development are holding weapons? Are there any specific historical events, philosophies, theories, or laws through which it can be justified?

Comment: Read US Declaration of Independence and Federalist Papers

Comment: The right to self defense is endowed by our creator (Declaration of Independence), it doesn't matter if you are "enlighted" or dumb as a rock, you have the right to defend yourself.

Comment: I still have to find any person of group who think that he or it has not every right to do whatever he or it does.

Comment: @user1873 Your creator also endowed George III with the right to rule over America ("by the grace of God" etc.), so I really don't think His endowments work very well as as guideline.

Comment: "cannot be justified" Why not? The question could either briefly explain or link to explanations to the concepts underlying the question. What exactly is an enlightened group? Why can the idea of using arms not be justified?

Answer (score 2):

It's not cliché or some blinder of American Exceptionalism to point squarely at the [Declaration of Independence](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript). I know of no other written argument that so succinctly puts the moral justification for open rebellion against one's government. This information dense quote says it all, in the context that life, liberty, and the pursuit of happiness are human rights:

> That to secure these rights, governments are instituted among men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed, that whenever any form of government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the right of the people to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new government, laying its foundation on such principles, and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most likely to effect their safety and happiness. Prudence, indeed, will dictate, that governments long established, should not be changed for light and transient causes; and accordingly all experience hath shown, that mankind are more disposed to suffer, while evils are sufferable, than to right themselves by abolishing the forms to which they are accustomed. But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, pursuing invariably the same object, evinces a design to reduce them under absolute despotism, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off such government, and to provide new guards for their future security.

Governments exist by and for the people they serve explicitly to protect those rights, and governments persistently derelict in this duty not only can be discarded, but should be discarded and replaced with great moral imperative.

The document continues from that point to assert that the Colonies had suffered thusly,  and lists the various ways. They do not say in the DoI that military action is permitted, but they also give no conditions at all. Such a tyranny must be overthrown. It is a moral imperative, a duty.

Comment: The catch is in *the people*. Where are the lines drawn? In addition to Donbas which is currently in the news there's also Catalonia, Tibet, Ireland, Palestine... A [comprehensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes) where the disputes arise precisely because of how those lines are drawn

Comment: @Raveesh I'm sorry, I don't exactly understand your comment. Do you mean some specific people apparently don't take arms? Do you mean territorial lines? I don't understand the point you're making.

Comment: Russia (that was USSR) does not like independent Ukraine (from it). Ukraine likewise does not like Donbas to self determine where it belongs. Who/How to arbitrate? Depends on the lines you draw delineating 'the people'.  You can go through the entire Wikipedia list above.  You will see a similar/analogous situation obtains in all cases.

Comment: @Raveesh The catch isn't in the people alone. It is in how the people are treated as well as what those people are seeking. From an international support perspective, the context of the situation is far more important than the independent actions happening on the ground.

Comment: @Raveesh I understand what you mean now. In practice, the winner is "right", or rather, the winner wins all rights. But this answer is about personal ethics. How do individuals justify sedition and insurrection?

Comment: Comes to the same @DavidS. The NATO countries viewpoint: *Russia is mass-murdering Ukrainians.* Russian viewpoint: *Ukraine is genociding its Russians for 8 years and Minsk is proof.* [Rest of the World](https://youtu.be/wmOePNsNFw0?t=520): *This fratricidal war is not ours. We'd rather stay out of it* So it comes down to how the lines of 'The people' are drawn

Comment: @fredsbend Much wisdom in your line "Winner is right = Winner wins all rights" As for the social vs individual dichotomy, when push comes to shove it breaks down: A non conforming view is an unacceptable view and ultimately a non view. See https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-03-03/stan-grant-tells-audience-member-to-leave-qanda/100880520

Answer (score 0):

[Article 20(4) of the Basic Law for the Federal Republic of Germany](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0111) (Germany's constitution) might be worth mentioning in this context. It grants the population the right to resistance against an attempt to de-democratize Germany:

> (1) The Federal Republic of Germany is a democratic and social federal state.
>
> (2) All state authority is derived from the people. It shall be exercised by the people through elections and other votes and through specific legislative, executive and judicial bodies.
>
> (3) The legislature shall be bound by the constitutional order, the executive and the judiciary by law and justice.
>
> (4) All Germans shall have the right to resist any person seeking to abolish this constitutional order if no other remedy is available.

The clause "if no other remedy is available" does of course leave a lot of room for interpretation. It's also not entirely explicit that the "right to resist" covers not just [nonviolent resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonviolent_resistance) but violent resistance as well.

Political radicals from all political fringes have tried to build arguments to legalize political terrorism based on this article. Needless to say that such arguments usually fall on deaf ears outside of these finge circles. Usually because their idea of "constitutional order" not having much to do with what mainstream society considers the "constitutional order" and/or because their chain of reasoning that the powers that be seek to abolish the constitutional order is obviously flawed.